# Необходимо распарсить дерево (JSON) по шаблону

Tags: javascript

У меня есть построенное дерево, у дерева есть уровни вложенности (depth), стоит задача:
взять 1 (depth : 1) уровени вложенности -> найти все его конечные дочерние элементы и положить в массив 1 уровня (пример то что на приходит и то что должно быть на выходе ниже)

На входе: пример дерева:

```
{
    "id": "43",
    "depth": 0,
    "node": [
        {
            "id": "5106",
            "depth": 1, // 1 УРОВЕНЬ
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5108",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5110",
                    "depth": 2,
                    "node": [
                        {
                            "id": "5112",
                            "depth": 3, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                            "node": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "51993",
                            "depth": 3, 
                            "node": [
                                {
                                    "id": "51190",
                                    "depth": 4, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                                    "node": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6758",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "6760",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5107",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5112",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5113",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "26517",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": []
        },
    ]
}
```

На выходе (то что нужно получить):

```
{
    "id": "43",
    "depth": 0,
    "node": [
        {
            "id": "5106",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": ["5108", "5112", "51190", "6758", "6760"]
        },
        {
            "id": "5107",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": ["5112", "5113"]
        },
        {
            "id": "26517",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": []
        },
    ]
}
```

---

```
const input = {
    "id": "43",
    "depth": 0,
    "node": [
        {
            "id": "5106",
            "depth": 1, // 1 УРОВЕНЬ
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5108",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5110",
                    "depth": 2,
                    "node": [
                        {
                            "id": "5112",
                            "depth": 3, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                            "node": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "51993",
                            "depth": 3, 
                            "node": [
                                {
                                    "id": "51190",
                                    "depth": 4, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                                    "node": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6758",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "6760",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5107",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5112",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5113",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "26517",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": []
        },
    ]
}    


function getOutput (input) {
        let output = {
            id: input.id,
            depth: input.depth,
            node: []
        };
        input.node.forEach(node => {
            let children = getChildren(node);
            output.node.push({
                id: node.id,
                depth: node.depth,
                children: children
            });
        });
        return output;
    }

function getChildren (node) {
    let children = [];
    node.node.forEach(node => {
        children.push(node.id);
        children = children.concat(getChildren(node));
    });
    return children;
}


console.log(getOutput(input))

log ->

{
    "id": "43",
    "depth": 0,
    "node": [
        {
            "id": "5106",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": [
                "5108",
                "5110",
                "5112",
                "51993",
                "51190",
                "6758",
                "6760"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5107",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": [
                "5112",
                "5113"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "26517",
            "depth": 1,
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const obj = {
    "id": "43",
    "depth": 0,
    "node": [
        {
            "id": "5106",
            "depth": 1, // 1 УРОВЕНЬ
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5108",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5110",
                    "depth": 2,
                    "node": [
                        {
                            "id": "5112",
                            "depth": 3, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                            "node": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "51993",
                            "depth": 3, 
                            "node": [
                                {
                                    "id": "51190",
                                    "depth": 4, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                                    "node": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6758",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "6760",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5107",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": [
                {
                    "id": "5112",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5113",
                    "depth": 2, // КОНЕЧНЫЙ
                    "node": []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "26517",
            "depth": 1,
            "node": []
        },
    ]
}    
obj.node = obj.node.map(o => {
    const obj = {
        id: o.id,
        depth: o.depth,
        children: []
    }
    item(o.node, obj.children)
    return obj
})
console.log(obj)

// Сбор массива
function item(arr, tar) {
    arr = arr.forEach(o => {
        if (o.node.length) item(o.node, tar)
        else tar.push(o.id)
    })
}
```